# How to prevent body click event, when select2 dropdown is clicked?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select2 dropdown like this (Using Select2_4.0.13 version)

```
<select id="animalType" class="modal animalClass" onchange="changeType()">
      <option value="0">Select Filter</option>
       <option value="1">Herbivores</option>
    <option value="2">Carnivores</option>
       <option value="3">Omnivores</option>
    <option value="4">Others</option>
</select>
```

I have initialized the dropdown like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#animalType).select2();
}
```

But I am not sure why the select2 is calling body click function

This is I defined in my body click event

```
$("body").click(function (e){
var assignType=["Node","Cluster","Server"];
if(!$(e.target).is(".modal, templateFilter")){
     $('select').select2('close'); 
}
}
```

The problem is the dropdown is automatically closed even before selecting the option.

This is not occuring when I used 3.4.8 version of Select2.

As per my analysis, Select2 3.4.8 is not calling the body click event when the select2 is initialized. But In 4.0.13 version, It is calling the body click event.

Can anyone help me to prevent the body click event being invoked by the select2?